# Get storage devices info in BIOS assembly

Tags: c, assembly, inline-assembly, bios

how could I get information about the storage devices connected to the PC (floppy, HDD, usb disk drive, flash drive) from BIOS using 8086 assembly . I'm using VS 2008. Can you point me to a reference book or some info? I want to detect all working such devices and be able to read and write to them. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look these up:

- Ralf Brown's Interrupt List
- HelpPC
- TechHelp
- The Undocumented PC: A Programmer's Guide to I/O, CPUs, and Fixed Memory Areas
- PCI System Architecture (and the like)